# Logic Apps with O365 - change "reply to"

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to change the email’s “Reply to” property when using Logic Apps’ O365 connector actions (either “forward email” or “send new email”)? If yes - how?

Context: We are building an email routing solution, where we need to “observe” some mailboxes and route incoming emails to other destination mailboxes basing on some rules. Owners of the destination mailboxes must be able to directly reply to the original sender. 
How to achieve this with Logic apps?

Comment: Does [Reply to email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365connector/#reply-to-email-(v3)) action meet your requirement ?

Comment: no, this is regular reply...